# Search datatable using single Search button and clear button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm implementing datatable ajax-grid where I'm loading data using the bigcommerce API. I've implemented a column-wise search box. But the problem with that is it searches in realtime. I don't want it. What I want to do is I want a search button and a clear button in the last column.

Now suppose I've entered a keyword in the search box of product name and also entered one keyword in SKU. Now when I press the search button it should search using that both keywords. How can I do the same?

Here's my code

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Image</th> 
                <th>Product SKU</th> 
                <th>Product Name</th> 
                <th>Price</th> 
                <th>Status</th> 
                <th>Actions</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tfoot> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Image</th> 
                <th>Product SKU</th> 
                <th>Product Name</th> 
                <th>Price</th> 
                <th>Status</th> 
                <th>Actions</th> 
            </tr> 
        </tfoot> 
    </table>
```

JS

```
$('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
$('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
  var title = $(this).text();

  $(this).html( '<input class="no_sort" type="text" />' );                  

  $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
    if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
        table
             .column(i)
             .search( this.value )
             .draw();
     }
  } );
} );
```

Using JS, I'm adding the filter just below the table headers

What I want: https://prnt.sc/pnzygy
What it currently looks like: https://prnt.sc/pnzz98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Var table=$('#example').DataTable();

table.column(2).search("sku").draw();
table.column(3).search("product name").draw();